# EDITED: Why Won't This Formula Do What I think It Should

Tags: excel, vba

EDITED THIS QUESTION:

Earlier I asked a question about excluding rows from a count if a cell is coloured. I think I've been able to figure out a function that will do what I want it to, but when I call the function in my spreadsheet it returns a #VALUE error and I'm not sure why.

```
Function CountRemaining(nameRange As Range, countRange As Range) As Integer
Dim TotalCount As Integer
Set nameCell = nameTarget
For Each nameCell In nameRange
    If nameCell.Interior.ColorIndex <> 12 Then
        Set countCell = countRange
        For Each countCell In countRange
            If countCell.Value = "x" Then
                TotalCount = TotalCount + 1
            End If
        Next countCell
    End If
    Next nameCell

CountRemaining = TotalCount
End Function
```

I give name range the range of people's names (the cells I color in manually when the item is received) and the range of the item goes into count range (denoted by an x for the item that they have).

Logically this function makes sense to me but I can't see the flaw. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I did not understand what you want to do ! can you demonstrate that by example with data ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/2xogY

This is some mock data. In the "Total Remaining" section, I want it to exclude the data in the 3rd row (because it's "gone").

Comment: Would it not be easier to change the `x` to something once it has been collected, say `c`for example, and use another formula similar to your countif x but with c?

Comment: @TysonMoyes from the picture you sent do you want to exclude item2 at row 3 from the total ? or what do you want to exclude ? from my understanding you want to exclude 3rd row (any row with name is green ) IS that right ?

Comment: Ideally, yes. But my boss wants a total count of everything we receive, including what has already been sent out, so I need both numbers.

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer that's exactly right! I'd like to exclude the whole row from the count

Comment: @TysonMoyes OK Cool ! thank you for the explanation... you could add a button with vba code that count the sum of the items (using for loop ) with if statement to exclude the green rows. that is if you want to use excel macros ! I am not sure if it is possible to write a formula to do that for you .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to add a new column next to the last name for example ( let name it as include/exclude ) and set this column to 0 or 1 based on the color of the lastname background color.

you can read the color of the cell by going to Excel's Name Manager ( under formula ) and create new and give it a name ( lastnamecolor). Then 
in the refers to field  insert the following formula : 
=GET.CELL(63,INDIRECT("rc[-1]",FALSE))

where 63 mean the background color of cell and rc[-1] means of the previous column .
now in the include/exclude column we inserted (next to the last name) put the following formula for all the rows:

=(IF(lastnamecolor=10,0,1))

this will check the color of the last name of each row and if it is green (=10) then it show 0 otherwise it show 1 .

now you should get 0 or 1 next to the last names and you can include this values in the formula that calculate the total by multiplying each item with this value before adding it to the total.